# Error on Joint Tables in php

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a query to select fields from 3 tables and join them together but I keep getting

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in....
```

Here is my table structure:

quote (id, name)
categories (id, category_name, category_slug)
in_category (id, quote_id, category_id)

and here is my query

```
$select_tags=mysql_query("SELECT

                        categories.id AS 'category_id',
                        categories.category_name AS 'categories.category_name',
                        categories.category_slug AS 'categories.category_slug',
                        in_category.category_id,
                        in_category.quote_id,
                        from categories, in_category
                        WHERE in_category.quote_id = '$quotes_id'

                        ");
```

Anything I run will end up to be an error with this query so surely there is something wrong I'm doing here - Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of single quotes for alias names in the query.

So it should be something as

```
categories.id AS category_id,

.......
```

Also use explicit JOIN

```
SELECT
categories.id AS category_id,
categories.category_name AS categories_category_name,
categories.category_slug AS categories_category_slug,
in_category.category_id,
in_category.quote_id
from categories
JOIN in_category on in_category.category_id = categories.id
WHERE in_category.quote_id = '$quotes_id'
```

Comment: I did and it didn't make any difference

Comment: ok what error you get ? did u try the same query in mysql directly ?

Comment: yeah on mysql i get the error on line 7 - I have no idea why but issue goes back to JOIN

Comment: So I ran this code and this is what I get in mysql #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from categories
JOIN in_category on in_category.category_id = categories.id
WHER' at line 7

Comment: Ah sorry my bad I had a small mistake `in_category.quote_id,` the comma was not needed here removed it and updated the answer. It should work now.